# Iterando em um array multidimensional

Tags: php, array-multidimensional

```
<?php
$data = array();
//questoes de user 1
$data['rows']['questions'][1] = array(
    array('id' => 1, 'type' => 'radio', 'name' => "Onde fica ilha de Santiago"),
    array('id' => 2, 'type' => 'radio', 'name' => "Onde fica tarafal"),
    array('id' => 3, 'type' => 'boolean', 'name' => "Cidade velha é a capital de Cabo Verde"),

);
$data['rows']['aresponses'][1] = array(
    '1' => array(
        array('id' => 1, 'name' => "No barlavanto"),
        array('id' => 2, 'name' => "No sotavento"),
        array('id' => 3, 'name' => "No norte do arquipélago"),
    ),
    '2' => array(
        array('id' => 1, 'name' => "Na ilha do fogo"),
        array('id' => 2, 'name' => "Na ilha de santiago"),
        array('id' => 3, 'name' => "Na ilha de brava"),
    ),
    '3' => array(
        array('id' => 1, 'name' => "Verdairo"),
        array('id' => 2, 'name' => "Falso"),
    ),

);
?>
```

Relacionando cada pergunda com uma lista de alternativas de resposta

Exemplo:

```
>       Pergunta:  Onde fica ilha de Santiago
>               
>       Alternativa1:  No barlavanto
>       Alternativa2:  No sotavento
>       Alternativa2   No norte do arquipélago
```

Comment: Só pegar o ID da [questions] e adicionar após o [aresponses][1][{ID}], assim faz um foreach de cada item.

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, o índice do array que contem as alternativas precisa iniciar em 0, assim como os índices que contém as perguntas, sendo assim a iteração do array entre as perguntas e respostas, vai ficar desta forma:

```
$data = array();
//questoes de user 1
$data['rows']['questions'][1] = array(
    array('id' => 1, 'type' => 'radio', 'name' => "Onde fica ilha de Santiago"),
    array('id' => 2, 'type' => 'radio', 'name' => "Onde fica tarafal"),
    array('id' => 3, 'type' => 'boolean', 'name' => "Cidade velha é a capital de Cabo Verde"),

);

$data['rows']['aresponses'][1] = array(
    0 => array(
        array('id' => 1, 'name' => "No barlavanto"),
        array('id' => 2, 'name' => "No sotavento"),
        array('id' => 3, 'name' => "No norte do arquipélago"),
    ),
    1 => array(
        array('id' => 1, 'name' => "Na ilha do fogo"),
        array('id' => 2, 'name' => "Na ilha de santiago"),
        array('id' => 3, 'name' => "Na ilha de brava"),
    ),
    2 => array(
        array('id' => 1, 'name' => "Verdairo"),
        array('id' => 2, 'name' => "Falso"),
    ),

);

$questoes      =  $data['rows']['questions'][1];

$alternativas  =  $data['rows']['aresponses'][1];

foreach ($questoes as $key => $value) {

    echo 'Questao: ' . $value['name'] . '<br />';

    echo 'Alternativas';

    foreach ($alternativas[$key] as $key2 => $value2 ) {

        echo 'Alternativa: ' . ($key2 + 1) . ' : ' . $value2['name'] . "<br />";

    }

    echo '<br /><br />';

}
```

Para testar o código fora do teu projeto, teste [Aqui](http://www.writephponline.com/)